# iOS Simulator memory alignment

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, memory-alignment

I am testing the alignment and i determine something strange with iOS simulator.(XCode 4.3.2 and XCode 4.5).

On iOS simulator, structures are aligned to 8 byte boundary even when **attribute** ((aligned (4))) is used to force 4 byte boundary. Check that its padded with **0x00000001** at the end to align 8 byte boundary.

If myStruct variable defined in global scope then simulator aligns it to 4-byte boundary, so it may be something related to stack.

Simulator is i386 so its 32-bit and it must be aligning to 4-byte boundary. So, what would be the reason, why is it aligning to 64-bit boundary? Is it a feature or a bug?

(I know it is not necessary to struggle with simulator but it may cause to stuck into subtle problems.)

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} myStruct;
//} __attribute__ ((aligned (4))) myStruct;

-(void)alignmentTest
{
    // Offset 16*n    (0x2fdfe2f0)
    int __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) force16ByteBoundary = 0x01020304; 

    // Offset 16*n-4  (0x2fdfe2ec)
    int some4Byte = 0x09080706;

    // Offset 16*n-12 (0x2fdfe2e4)
    myStruct  mys;

    mys.a = 0xa1b1c1d1;
    mys.b = 0xf2e28292;

    NSLog(@"&force16ByteBoundary: %p / &some4Byte: %p / &mys: %p",
       &force16ByteBoundary, &some4Byte, &mys);
}
```

(**EDIT** Optimizations are off, -O0)

- **Simulator(iOS 5.1) results;**

  > (lldb) x `&mys` -fx
  >
  > **0xbfffda60**: 0xa1b1c1d1 0xf2e28292 **0x00000001** 0x09080706
  >
  > **0xbfffda70**: 0x01020304
  >
  > &force16ByteBoundary: 0xbfffda70 / &some4Byte: 0xbfffda6c / &mys:
  >   0xbfffda60
- **Device(iOS 5.1) results;**

  > (lldb) x `&mys` -fx
  >
  > **0x2fdfe2e4**: 0xa1b1c1d1 0xf2e28292 0x09080706 0x01020304
  >
  > &force16ByteBoundary: 0x2fdfe2f0 / &some4Byte: 0x2fdfe2ec / &mys:
  >   0x2fdfe2e4

(**NEW FINDINGS**)

```
- On Simulator and Device;
    - Building for Release or Debug does not make any difference for alignments.
    - Local or global variables of "long long", double types are aligned to 8 byte boundary although they must be aligned to 4 byte boundary. 
    - There is no problem with global variables of structs.
- On Simulator;
    - Local variables of structs are aligned to 8 byte boundary even when there is only a char member in the struct.
```

(**EDIT**)

I could only find out the "Data Types and Data Alignment" for iOS [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARMv6FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009021-SW1).
(Also, they could be inferred from [ILP32 alignments here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html))

Comment: Simulator is Intel, iDevice is ARM...different architectures...ARM is way more restrictive with byte alignment and Intel is more forgiving.

Comment: The device you are running the simulator, is 64 bits ?

Comment: Is the result the same in debug and release builds?

Comment: I have already considered bitness of Mac OS X, may be that's the real reason. Just need official confirmation of it's requirement(required if there is a direct mapping between OS X and simulator's memory.). I will try debug and release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the alignment attributes only affect the relative alignment of items inside a struct.  This allows backward-compatibility with code that wants to just bulk-copy data into a structure directly from the network or binary file.

The alignment attributes won't affect the alignment of local variables allocated on the stack.  The ordering and alignment of items on the stack is not guaranteed and will generally be aligned optimally for each item for the device.  So, if a 386-based device can fetch a 64-bit long-long from memory in a single operation by 8-byte aligning them, it will do so.  Some processors actually lose dramatic amounts of performance if data is not fully aligned.  Some processors can throw exceptions for attempting to read data that is not properly aligned.